# When doing a backup, does it make sense to "copy as symlink" when source and destination are on the same volume, and "copy the content" otherwise?

Tags: windows, backup, symbolic-link

Years after years, I'm using more and more symlinks between directories for many purposes.

Let's say I do a backup of `D:\`.

When configuring the backup task, you usually have two choices:

- either the backup program **"follows symlinks"** and then it will copy the *actual* content...

  ...  but then if `D:\projectA\100GB_folder_link\` is a symlink to `D:\projectB\100GB_folder\`, then **the backup program** will copy the data twice, wasting 100 GB.
- or you can ask the backup program to **not follow symlinks**, and then it will only copy the link itself (and not the content)...

  ... but then if `D:\projectC\100GB_folder_link\` is a symlink to `E:\projectD\100GB_folder\`, the actual data will not be copied during the backup! Which is a problem because, then, the backup will *not* contain this data.

**How to handle this problem?**

I thought about the following rule, but not sure if it covers all cases:

- for each symlink, if `src` and `target` are on the same volume/partition, then only copy the link (`follow_symlinks = False`)
- for each symlink, if `src` and `target` are **not** on the same volume/partition, then copy the *content* (`follow_symlinks = True`)

Side remark: Is it a common feature of backup programs to have such a mixed rule? (such as Windows built-in robocopy, or other tools)

Comment: Which backup program are you using. For example [robocopy /sl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) does: "Don't follow symbolic links and instead create a **copy of the link**".

Comment: @harrymc Along the years, I used many different programs: xxcopy, robocopy, SyncBack, Syncthing, etc. Most of them have an option like the one you mentioned: enable/disable follow symlinks. Here the question is about having a mix of both.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: As mentioned in the post @harrymc, both solutions (follow symlinks or *not* follow symlinks) have their own drawbacks (see the real-life examples in the 2 first bullet points). I'm looking for a general solution to this problem (not specific to a particular program, but rather the general idea).

Comment: If you're looking for a backup program that decides intelligently on its own what to do with symlinks, I'm afraid you will need to create your own program or script.